# Как создать присоединенное свойство коллекции?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть WebBrowser, взаимодействовать с которыми я могу только через ObjectForScripting и задача состоит в том что нужно рендерить коллекцию в браузере в виде графических елементов. WebBrowser - sealed и особо изменять его не получается а нужен функционал как ItemsControl.ItemsSource. Конечно можно создать attached property `List<T>` и делать биндинг к нему, но я посмотрел на ItemsSource свойство и мне интересно как коллекция `IEnumerable<T>` биндиться к `IEnumerable` и как потом делается биндинг к свойствам?

```
[System.ComponentModel.Bindable(true)]
public System.Collections.IEnumerable ItemsSource { get; set; }
```

Comment: Да, конечно можно. Сейчас напишу.

Comment: А можно больше деталей? Что у вас есть и что нужно? Вам нужно отображать данные не в WPF-контроле, а в WebBrowser? То есть, данные у вас есть, а нужно именно отображение?

Comment: @VladD, да, на вход JavaScript должен получать изменения в коллекции и изменения свойств елементов коллекции

Comment: Ну хорошо, а почему бы не завести объект, содержащий как поля WebBrowser и Items, и подписаться на NotifyCollectionChanged у Items? Binding у вас не выйдет так просто, т. к. WebBrowser этого не умеет.

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите.

Для начала, если вы создаёте attached property, вы его можете создавать где угодно. Например, давайте создадим attached property `NumberOfColumns` для `Grid`, чтобы не вбивать его вручную. Заодно оно будет делать что-то полезное: создавать нужное колиество колонок, чтобы не возиться с `<ColumnDefinition .../>`.

Мы кладём определение в статический класс, нам даже не обязательно наследоваться от `DependencyObject`. Создавать attached property проще всего при помощи сниппета `propa`.

```cs
// этот класс будет содержать наше attached property
public static class GridExt
{
    // к геттеру присоединили атрибут, чтобы отображалось только у Grid
    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(Grid))]
    // стандартный геттер...
    public static int GetNumberOfRows(DependencyObject obj) =>
        (int)obj.GetValue(NumberOfRowsProperty);

    // ... и сеттер
    public static void SetNumberOfRows(DependencyObject obj, int value) =>
        obj.SetValue(NumberOfRowsProperty, value);

    // объявляет attached property
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberOfRowsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("NumberOfRows", typeof(int), typeof(GridExt),
            new PropertyMetadata(0, (o, args) => OnNumberOfRowsChanged((Grid)o)));

    // это будет вызываться при изменении значения
    static void OnNumberOfRowsChanged(Grid g)
    {
        var numberOfRows = GetNumberOfRows(g);
        // приведём реальное количество колонок к запрошенному
        while (g.RowDefinitions.Count > numberOfRows)
            g.RowDefinitions.RemoveAt(g.RowDefinitions.Count - 1);
        while (g.RowDefinitions.Count < numberOfRows)
            g.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()
                                 {
                                     Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
                                 });
    }
}
```

Можно использовать в XAML, чтобы сослаться на наше attached property, нужно указать имя класса и namespace:

```xaml
<Grid local:GridExt.NumberOfRows="3">
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Border Background="Red" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Border Background="Gold" Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

Получается вот такая картинка:

[image: Einigkeit und Recht und Freiheit]

---

Attached property можно использовать и по-другому. Например, их можно использовать как просто хранилище значений, и привязываться к этим значениям из стилей.

---

Дополнение:
Если речь идёт не о View-объектах, а об объектах VM и модели, там правильным решением является агрегация: создайте объект-обёртку `UserWithRelatedUsers` (или как там правильно должен называться такой класс), который содержит `User`, а также подчинённый ему `List<User>` (или, возможно, `List<UserWithRelatedUsers>`), и привязывайтесь к нему.

Comment: спасибо, но у меня сложно с объяснением, я имел в виду как сделать что-то типа своего AttachedItemsSource (IEnumerable наверное должен быть) и AttachedDisplayMemberPath, тем самым отделив вид и логику,  поправил немного вопрос

Comment: @MikeWaters: Подождите, а класс `User` — это View или ViewModel?

Comment: User это ViewModel

Comment: @MikeWaters: дополнил ответ

Comment: я лично думаю что нужно както трансформировать IList<T> к IList и дальше делать коллекцию View елементов с свойством DataContext (куда ставить T) и от каждого View елемента делять Binding к DataContext

Comment: @MikeWaters: Подождите, а зачем трансформировать? Расскажите, что у вас есть, и что нужно, по идее, это решается проще.

Comment: именил вопрос, весь смысл в том, как сделать биндинг не зная в View какой тип приходит от ViewModel, UI елемент должен биндиться к свойствам DataContext, но не знать что такое DataContext